# MySQL dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

#### Problem description

I have the following table (SampleTable) which contains dynamic columns and want to sort, search and paginate dynamic columns.

Note: The actual table has more rows than 6.

SampleTable

| Id (asc) | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | BotName | Botx |
| x | BotLevel | 0 |
| x | BotVersion | 0.1.0 |
| y | BotName | Boty |
| y | BotLevel | 1 |
| y | BotVersion | 0.2.0 |

I've tried things similar to the following, but it fails on pagination (unsure if sub-queries maintain the order).

```
select * from SampleTable where Id in (
      select * from (
        select a.Id
        from SampleTable a
          where a.Id in (
            select * from (
              select Id from SampleTable
                where `Value` = {query}
                group by Id
            ) as tmpa
          )
    ...group by...
    ...pagination...
```

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW`...

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but it should give you the idea:

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable JOIN (
    SELECT Id FROM (
        SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
        FROM SampleTable
        WHERE `Value` = ? -- don't you want a condition on `Column` as well?
        GROUP BY Id
    ) AS r
    WHERE r.rownum BETWEEN ? AND ? -- do your pagination here
) AS i USING (Id)
```

Using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I didn't test this yet either, but guessing we can order by `Column` with something similar to `ORDER BY FIELD(Column, 'BotName') DESC, Value DESC` within the sub-query?

Comment: Why are you searching for a Value without specifying the Column?

Comment: Hmm, yes probably I'd need conditions for `Column` and `Value` at the same time so we can have something that mimics `select * from t where t.col = {q}`, with this implementation I guess we're querying any `Column`.

Comment: Yes sorry we do need to specify the `Column` as well.

Comment: Right -- in that case, you don't need to sort by `Column` because there should only be one value for `Column` in your matched rows.

Comment: True, we'll just sort by `Value`. :)